# Difficulty getting Ruby to express Geocoder method in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, geocoding

I'm very new to Ruby and trying to use it for some very simple geocode scripting. Essentially grabbing addresses out of a CSV, passing it to the Geocoder, and then outputting geocoded attributes of the addresses (plus some other fields) out to a new CSV.

Unfortunately while it seems like I can get Geocoded objects into an array, I'm having difficulty performing a method on the elements in the Geocoded array. I know that if I don't put the geocoded elements into an array, but just into a variable that gets overwritten with each iteration, the latitude and longitude elements work.

Note: I also realize that using the for x ... syntax is not the preferred way to do a loop through an array in Ruby, but I couldn't figure out an easy way to then concatenate the resulting geocoded information with the year of each observation.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
require 'csv'
require 'geocoder'

Geocoder.configure(
#geocoding service 
  :lookup => :nominatim
 )



address = []
year=[]
y=[]
a=[]
out=[]


CSV.foreach(File.path("realproperty_small.csv")) do |col|
    address  << col[2]
    year <<col[10]
end



for x in 1..address.length

    y[x] = address[x].to_s + "City,State"

    puts y[x]


    a[x]  = Geocoder.search(y[x])

    out[x] = y[x]  + "," + a[x].latitude.to_s + "," + a[x].longitude.to_s + "," + year[x]

    puts out[x]

sleep 1

end
```

UPDATE: Because I couldn't figure out how to get the latitude and longitude methods to evaluate the geocoded array elements, I decided to come up with a process that doesn't put the geocoded information into an array. Rather I just create a geocoded variable that gets written over as I enumerate through my list of addresses. The code below works successfully, but I would still love some insight as to why my original code wouldn't work.

```
require 'csv'
require 'geocoder'

Geocoder.configure(
    #geocoding service 
  :lookup => :nominatim
)

address = []
year=[]
full=[]

CSV.foreach(File.path("realproperty.csv")) do |col|
    address  << col[2]
    year <<col[10]
end

File.open('geocoded_addresses.csv', 'w') do |f1| #opens a csv file to print out output lines below. Don't understand what the f1 is for.
for x in 1 .. address.length #loops through each address

    y[x] =  address[x].to_s + "New York, NY" #concatenates a city to allow for the address to be geocoded

    z = Geocoder.search(y[x])  #this creates a new object with the geocoded information for the y[x] address

    z.each do |a|

        f1.puts y[x].to_s + "," + a.latitude.to_s + "," + a.longitude.to_s + "," + year[x].to_s  #this takes the address and concatenates it with the latitude and longitude data (z, which becomes a), as well as the year data, and outputs it to the csv

        full << x.to_s + "., " + y[x].to_s + "," + a.latitude.to_s + "," + a.longitude.to_s + "," + year[x].to_s #this outputs to an array what is going into the csv file, numbering the observations

        puts full[x].to_s #this prints in the command window what is being outputed to csv

    end

sleep 1

end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the entire CSV into an array using `read` command as follows:

```
data_array = CSV.read("realproperty_small.csv")
```

`data_array` will be a 2 dimensional array i.e. `data_array[row_index][col_index]`

To do a `for` loop, you simply enumerate on the array itself. In this case, it will enumerate on the rows like this:

```
data_array.each do |row|
  y[x] = row[2].to_s + "City,State"
  ...
end
```

See for more info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_iterators.htm

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I tried the data array, CSV.read option that you suggested, but I still ran into the problem of trying to apply a method to the geocoded array elements.

Comment: An array object by default does not have longitude & latitude methods associated to it. Have you inspected what the geocoded array element looks like i.e. whether its an object of a certain class, a hash, an array, or some combination? If you can't figure it out, then post the output of your geocoded elements so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I believe the geocoded array element is comprised of geocode objects, which themselves are arrays of different geocode elements (e.g. latitude, longitude, etc.). See above where I was able to hack out a fix that doesn't involve putting the geocoded objects into an array.